# Accessing multiple property files with @PropertyResource in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Using the new `@PropertySource` annotation in Spring 3.1, how can you access multiple property files with Environment?

Currently I have:

```
@Controller
@Configuration 
@PropertySource(
    name = "props",
    value = { "classpath:File1.properties", "classpath:File2.properties" })
public class TestDetailsController {


@Autowired
private Environment env;
/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {

    String file1Name = env.getProperty("file1.name","file1.name not found");
            String file2Name = env.getProperty("file2.name","file2.name not found");

            System.out.println("file 1: " + file1Name);
            System.out.println("file 2: " + file2Name);

    return "home";
}
```

The result is the correct file name from *File1.properties*, but *file2.name* not found. How can access *File2.properties*?

Comment: I would think twice before making the controller `@Configuration` class - `@Configuration` classes are processed in a different way than the normal spring beans it's hard to predict how it affects the bean life-cycles and the behavior .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are two different approaches: 
the first one is to use the PropertyPlaceHolder in your applicationContext.xml:
[beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/properties/*.properties"/>
```

the namespace to add is `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"`

If you want a direct access of a key to a String variable in your controller, use:

```
@Value("${some.key}")
private String valueOfThatKey;
```

The second approach is to use the `util:properties` in you applicationContext.xml:

```
<util:properties id="fileA" location="classpath:META-INF/properties/a.properties"/>
<util:properties id="fileB" location="classpath:META-INF/properties/b.properties"/>
```

using the namesapce `xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"` schemaLocations: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd`

Then in your Controller:

```
@Resource(name="fileA")
private Properties propertyA;

@Resource(name="fileB")
private Properties propertyB;
```

If you want a value from the files, just use the method `getProperty(String key)`

Comment: How does the first approach address the question? Adding a wildcard is not really pointing to multiple specific properties files. Could you please explain how multiple locations can be specified?

Comment: *.properties, it will scan folders in classpath to match all your properties. It was spring 3 and old, I'm sure there is a better way now. but that should still work regardless.

Answer (score 65):

If you can migrate to **Spring 4.x** the problem has been solved with the new [@PropertySources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySources.html) annotation:

```java
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("/file1.properties"),
        @PropertySource("/file2.properties")
})
```

Answer (score 16):

Multiple `Properties` can be accessed in Spring by either,

- @PropertySource( {"name1", "name2"} )
- @PropertySorces( { @PropertySource("name1"), @PropertySource("name2") } )

Example of @PropertySource,

```
@PropertySource({
        "classpath:hibernateCustom.properties",
        "classpath:hikari.properties"
})
```

Example of @PropertySources,

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:hibernateCustom.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:hikari.properties")
})
```

After you specify `properties` path you can access them through `Environment` instance as you usually did

### NOTE: Only these simply did not work for me though

I was getting compilation `error` as I was using property values to configure my app context. I tried all that I found through web but they did not work for me !

**Until I configured Spring context as below,**

```
applicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
applicationContext.refresh();
```

Example

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        // register config class i.e. where i used @PropertySource
        applicationContext.register(AppContextConfig.class);
        // below 2 are added to make @PropertySources/ multi properties file to work
        applicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
        applicationContext.refresh();

        // other config
    }
}
```

For your information, I am using **Spring 4.3**

Comment: @PropertySource( {"name1", "name2"} ) - worked for me. I am loading two config properties, one in classpath and another in external location.
I gave like this -
@PropertySource({"classpath:/app.properties", "file:/C:/my_dir/config.properties"})