# Spring MVC How can i use multiple property file

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using single .property file as

```
@PropertySource("classpath:messages.properties")
public class BasicController {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;   
 .....
...
}
```

How can i use multiple property file. I saw [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505078/accessing-multiple-poperty-files-with-propertyresource-in-spring) but its not using `@PropertySource`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring 4.0, you can use this annotation

```
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:/app.properties")})
```

or if you are using spring 3.0+,

you can use either mention the configuration in config file like below or call the setLocations method in your class directly.

In the latter case, you will not require to use the PropertySource annotation.

```
<bean id="propertiesPlacholder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >  
     <property name="locations">  
       <list>  
           <value>classpath:/app1.properties</value>  
           <value>classpath:/app2.properties</value>  
       </list>  
    </property>  
 </bean>
```

you can use property in those files as below

```
@Controller
public class BasicController {

    @Value
    String name;   
 .....
...
}
```

if name is available as key in property file..it will be injected here..

Comment: how will i call `app1.properties` in my controller using second method

Comment: you dont have to call..just use the value of the properties in that file directly using @ Value  example @Value String name;

Comment: NO what i am asking is how can i get value from particular file only

Comment: like in my question i can get property using `env.getProperty('X')` and this is easy to access with dynamic key. SO i want to access in this fashion.

Comment: i am not sure whats your business need to get the property value using only getProperty() method..we ultimately need to get the value from properties file right..i used to get using @value only alwas..its very simple..

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `@PropertySources` like

```
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:jdbc.properties"),@PropertySource("classpath:paypalConfig.properties")})
```

Or you can use `@PropertySource` like

```
@PropertySource(value{"classpath:jdbc.properties","classpath:paypalConfig.properties"})
```

Once you do this you can access values corresponding a key in the property files using `Environment` variable like so

```
environment.getProperty("YOUR_KEY_IN_PROPERTY_FILE");
```