# Spring mvc : Access properties file value in controller without @Value

Tags: spring, file, properties

I have a properties file for messages in my Spring application.I want to access these value directly in controller.How can i do this ?.
**Note:** I don't want to use **@Value** annotation to store data in another variable.

Comment: For messages use a `MessageSource` that way you also have I18N if you ever need it and the ability to replace parts of the message with values.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference this question and answer regarding accessing files directly within controller.
It is what i used to implement mine.

[Accessing multiple property files with @PropertyResource in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505078/accessing-multiple-poperty-files-with-propertyresource-in-spring)

Comment: Thnks @Aeseir, when i am using private static String testValue = "testvalue";it stores testvalue as string in variable not the value from properties file.

Comment: Update the answer to reflect a source i used to develop mine. Check it out and it should have the answers you need.

Answer (score 1):

As M.Deinum suggested already, you should have a MessageSource bean definition if the purpose of the properties file is to externalize messages.  A message source is automatically picked by the application context, meaning it is available for injection in every other bean. You can autowire it for example in your controller:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

and then use its methods to access any message in any locale