# Spring: Combining PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and Environment

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-boot

I have a project that contains many .properties files and these property files vary alot in number. I do not want to import each individual property with the:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:some.properties")
```

So I tried loading all the properties from the directory by using the following simplified example code:

```
@Configuration
@Import(SomeClass.class)
public class SimpleConfiguration {

    private static final String TABLE_DIR = "src/main/resources/tables";
    private static final String TABLE_RESOURCE = "/tables/";  

    @Autowired
    public SomeClass someClass; 

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Path dir = Paths.get(TABLE_DIR);
        List<ClassPathResource> allProperties = new ArrayList<>();
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir)) {
            for (Path file : stream) {
                allProperties.add(new ClassPathResource(TABLE_RESOURCE + file.getFileName()));
            }
        } catch (IOException | DirectoryIteratorException x) {              
            System.err.println(x);
        }
        ClassPathResource[] props = allProperties.toArray(new ClassPathResource[allProperties.size()]);
        Resource[] resources = props;       
        properties.setLocations(resources);
        properties.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return properties;
    }       
}
```

The simplified example class

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void doSomething() {
        String tableName = "person";
        String someValue = env.getProperty(tableName + ".primaryKey");
    }
}
```

When trying to get a value the `env.getProperty` Throws a `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null` because the `Environment` object does not contain any of the resources that I preloaded with the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`

How do I retrieve a property after configuring `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and is it still possible to do it with the autowired `Environment` object?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505078/accessing-multiple-poperty-files-with-propertyresource-in-spring