# Load multiple external configuration file in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties-file

How to load multiple external configuration properties file in spring boot. Please find the below command to load external properties file when run the jar file.
"java -jar -Dspring.config.location= myBootProject.jar" 
Like we add one or two configuration path, but when we add more than two configuration then how would we configure?

Comment: Did you try "@PropertySources({
  @PropertySource("classpath:env1.properties"),
  @PropertySource("classpath:env2.properties")
})"?? Or you try including multiple properites in main property file using "include = env1.properties include = env2.properties"

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/a/20713910/3128638

Answer (score 0):

In spring you can do like below:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({
    "classpath:app-config.properties",
    "classpath:dtabase.properties" 
})
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;
}
```

If you are using spring4 and Java8 or Greater:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:app-config.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
})
public class AppConfig {
    //configuration classes
}
```

If a property key is duplicated, the last declared file will ‘win’ and override.

Read this for more information and complete samples
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

Hope it helps!